# How can I download images from a list of links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, download

I have a list of links to images (about 5000 lines), and I need to know how I can download all it fast. Please help me with my code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

catname = 'amateur'

def getimg (count, endcount):
    while (count < endcount):
      urllib.request.urlretrieve(URLS[count], catname+'/images/'+catname+str(count)+'.jpg')
      URLS[count] = catname+'/images/'+catname+str(count)+'.jpg'
      count = count + 1

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as e:
    e.submit(getimg, 0, 5000)
```

It works fine but slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code download 5000 images 50 times. Try following:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

catname = 'amateur'

def getimg(count):
    localpath = '{0}/images/{0}{1}.jpg'.format(catname, count)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(URLS[count], localpath)
    URLS[count] = localpath

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as e:
    for i in range(5000):
        e.submit(getimg, i)
```